# extracting type parameters in scala

Tags: scala

I have a piece of code that matches on a case class and then invokes a function based on the type and an extracted value:

```
def resolveByType[T](ids: List[Any]) = ids map (id => resolver.resolve[T](id))

override def resolve(deferred: Vector[Deferred[Any]], ctx: Any): Vector[Future[Any]] = deferred flatMap {
  case DeferAccounts(ids) => resolveByType[Account](ids)
  case DeferLocations(ids) => resolveByType[Location](ids)
  case DeferDelegates(ids) => resolveByType[EconomicUnit](ids)
  case DeferMUs(ids) => resolveByType[MunicipalUnit](ids)

  case _ =>
    List(Future.fromTry(Try(List[Any]())))
}
```

The case classes are defined as follows

```
case class DeferAccounts(accounts: List[String]) extends Deferred[List[Option[Account]]]
case class DeferLocations(loctions: List[String]) extends Deferred[List[Option[Location]]]
case class DeferDelegates(delegates: List[String]) extends Deferred[List[Option[EconomicUnit]]]
case class DeferMUs(delegates: List[String]) extends Deferred[List[Option[MunicipalUnit]]]
```

As you can see, all I need is that inner type parameter and the list. I'm trying to figure out the most *scala-y* way to do this. Seems like a lot of boilerplate code right now. Is there a clean way to extract the list and type parameter programmatically instead of declaratively, as it's being done now, or is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Would be clearer if you added the expected return type

Comment: Having so much `Any` is weird for me

Comment: Pattern matching is the default way to determine the runtime type of a case class instance. There is no other way to derive `T` from a `Deferred[Any]`, except reflection.

Another approach is not to discard the type information in the first place by using a collection which preserves the types of its elements (e.g. an `HList` from the shapeless library).

Comment: @devkat that sounds like an answer.. happy to accept it as such if you move it down below.